# How can I take a heap dump on Java 5 without garbage collecting first?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

We have a long running server application running Java 5, and profiling it we can see the old generation growing slowly over time. It's correctly freed on a full GC, but I'd like to be able to look at the unreachable objects in Eclipse MAT using a heap dump. I've successfully obtained a heap dump using +XX:HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak, but the JVM always does a GC before dumping the heap. Apparently this doesn't happen on Java 6 but we're stuck on 5 for now. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a 3rd-party profiler such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/), which may allow you to take snapshots without kicking off the GC first. Added bonus, you can take a snapshot without the whole ctrl-break shenanigans.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have a copy of JProfiler, but I didn't realise it could do this. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 15):

use jconsole or visualvm or jmc or ... other jmx management console.
open HotSpotDiagnostic in com.sun.management.
select method [dumpHeap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap-java.lang.String-boolean-)  and input two parameters:

- path to the dump file
- (true/false) dump only live objects. use `false` to dump all objects.

Note that the dump file will be written by the JVM you connected to, not by JVisualVM, so if the JVM is running on a different system, it will be written on that system.

[image]

Comment: Note that VisualVM requires the `VisualVM-MBeans` plugin for this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the standard jmap tool shipped with the JDK? 
The jmap toll was officially introduced in Java 5.

Example command line:
/java/bin/jmap -heap:format=b

The result can be processed with the standard jhat tool or with GUI applications such as MAT.

Answer (score 3):

I have some code here that can programmatically take a heap dump over JMX:

Link: [JmxHeapDumper.java](http://code.google.com/p/perfbench/source/browse/trunk/perfbench/jmeter-utils/src/main/java/jmeterutils/JmxHeapDumper.java)

The comments in the source code contain 2 links to articles that contained useful information about how to take heap dumps.  I don't know for sure but if you are in luck, perhaps the JMX approach would have some way of avoiding the GC.  Hope this helps !

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll take a look and see if it GCs beforehand or not. Being able to do it programmatically seems pretty useful, actually.

Answer (score -1):

jProfiler ([ej-technologies](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)) can do this.