# How can I disable the Systemic GC that occurs when I trigger a heap dump in WebSphere?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, websphere, heap-dump

I want to capture the objects that are getting collected during the System GC that occurs when I generate a heap dump.  Is there a way to disable that System GC?

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: IBM, sorry, I should have noted that.  Though I did tag it as WebSphere... :)

Comment: A similar post here: [How can I take a heap dump on Java 5 without garbage collecting first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268336/how-can-i-take-a-heap-dump-on-java-5-without-garbage-collecting-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate "system dump" instead of "heap dump". I haven't found any documentation on that, but I just tried and it seems that "system dump" doesn't trigger "system GC".

The "system dump" can be requested with `generateSystemDump` JMX operation. If you prefer to use `kill -3` command, then you'll probably need to add an environment variable to your JVM:

```
JAVA_DUMP_OPTS=ONDUMP(SYSDUMP)
```

The "system dump" needs to be processed with `jextract` tool before loading to Eclipse MAT. System dump is also much larger than heap dump, mainly because it contains not only object tree, but also the actual object data.

Comment: ... and the list of objects you're looking will be accessible via "Unreachable Objects Histogram" in MAT.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  +1 for MAT reference.

Comment: @MarcinPłonka is this generateSystemDump JMX operation is only native to WebSphere Application Server?

Answer (score 2):

In an IBM JRE you can disable explicit GC by adding `-Xdisableexplicitgc` as a JVM argument. However based on [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/troubleshootingjava/entry/when_is_a_system_gc_not_a_system_gc2?lang=en) there seems that this argument will not help.

Maybe a PMR to IBM support would help.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Hotspot, there are no parameters influencing the behavior of the VM when dumping a Heap. Usually, a GC collection is triggered before dumping a heap.

You can at least enable class histograms printing before/after a Full GC - this way you will see which objects were collected. (`XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC`)

You can also try `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` but I do not think this will help. When I collect a heap dump I always notice some objects being collected.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this post and I thought I'd put my two bob in. You can generate a system core via the WebSphere Adminconsole:
Navigate to Troubleshooting > Java dumps and cores.
Select the server(s) to collect dumps from.
Click on System Dump to produce a system core.

You also don't need to jextract the system core if you only need to do heap memory analysis in MAT. The system core also has a lot more useful diagnostic data than a heapdump,most times you can see the stack of the thread that is leaking heap memory