# Heap size discrepancies in VisualVM vs Eclipse MAT

Tags: java, visualvm, heap-dump, eclipse-mat

I'm trying to analyze the memory usage of my Java app. In VisualVM I see the Heap size as ~733M:

[image]

But when I exported the heap dump to Eclipse MAT, it shows as 36.6MB:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Though it doesn't change the question, the 733M is irrelevant, the 257M used is the figure that matters.

Answer (score 1):

duplicate: [Why is my Java heap dump size much smaller than used memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271731/why-is-my-java-heap-dump-size-much-smaller-than-used-memory)

TLDR; heap dump triggered garbage collection and dump shows the "Used heap"

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, viewing the "Used heap" in VisualVM is before garbage collection and doing heap dump, it's the size after garbage collection?

Comment: I don't know for sure what VisualVM does, but my understanding is the same as yours. I can suggest a talk I visited lately "HotSpot Internals: Signals, Safepoints and NullPointers – Volker Simonis" https://2017.geekout.ee/videos/#day2-03 it's pretty hardcore and not about VisualVM, but I think will give some insight.

Comment: Sorry my comment might not be clear. I meant to, confirming my understanding about your answer. Are you saying that the difference I'm seeing is because doing a heap dump ***triggers garbage collection*** as opposed to viewing the heap while the application is running is ***before*** the garbage collection?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying.