# Execute heap dump in remote Java 8+ JVM without first executing a Garbage Collecting

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, heap-memory, visualvm

I am using VisualVM to extract a Heap Dump from a tomcat that is consuming a lot of memory resources. It starts consuming around 1GB but gradually reaches 5-6GB. It has peaks where the CPU is at 100% and where the memory is close to 99%.

I am trying to investigate this event by extracting heap dump, but every time I run a Heap Dump with the VisualVM software it runs a full Garbage Collection first which causes the heap memory to go from 5-6GB at the time of the request to around 1GB, and the heap dump extract that it extracts is 1GB, when I want it to extract the extract from the moment before the GC

Reading this thread [How can I take a heap dump on Java 5 without garbage collecting first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268336/how-can-i-take-a-heap-dump-on-java-5-without-garbage-collecting-first) I have seen that I should use the value of "live" to false to prevent this from happening, but I can't find how to do it in VisualVM. I am connecting to the server using an SSH connection and tunneling, so the remote server does not have JDK installed.

How can I extract the entire heap dump remotely? Any advice to deal with this memory consumption? I am investigating the code in case there could be an error that causes consumption, but the fact that when a full GC is run the memory is restored to normal levels makes me suspicious.

Comment: If a GC causes the memory to go down, it's probably not an application issue. Try changing the GC settings (maybe so it is doing collections earlier or that you have a bigger region size for the young generation). My guess is that you just have a lot of objects in the old generation.

Comment: If the heap size gradually reaches 6G, and then falls without triggering a GC overhead limit exceeded exception, then I'd say everything is okay. Do you have a symptom (e.g. some requests take much longer than expected) which makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: jvm can do that automatically when [there's memory error](https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture#automatically)

Comment: This sounds entirely, 100% normal for a JVM application.  It is normal for it to consume all the memory it is given access to, to perform a garbage collection when that threshold is reached, and for that number to go down.  If you want it to consume less memory, cap the heap size lower.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448003/139985, you can use `jcmd` (without the `:live` option) to get a heap dump without running the GC first.  Try running `jcmd` in a shell on the remote machine if you can't figure out how to make VisualVM do it.